# Delegate methods not invoked for nssplitview present on top of another nssplitview

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

I have a horizontal NSSplitView which sits on top of right sub view of another vertical NSSplitView. I have delegate methods to constraint the left sub view from resizing. But the same delegate methods are never invoked for the horizontal NSSplitView sitting on top. What can be done to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us some code?  Are you reusing the same object as the delegate for both split views?

Comment: all the splitviews have different IBOutlets attached to it. Also the  top horizontal splitview is attached to the bottom right subview of split view through add view method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `delegate method` is fired for the `Left Split view controller` but not for the `Right split view controller`, then most likely you haven't set the delegate for the `Right Split View Controller`.

If you create the right split from an Xcode template, then it will be created in Interface builder from a `nib` file. Open `Interface builder`, then right-click drag and connect the `delegate` property to the object that you want to be the delegate.

If the `Right split view controller` object isn't created in a nib, then you will need to connect this up in code.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Delegates were missing. Binding of delegates solved it.